# How can a 2 level multidimensional array be changed to n levels?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [1g27] => Array
        (
            [42] => AAAAA
            [52] => BBBBB
            [4] => 2g4
        )
    [2g4] => Array
        (
            [9] => CCCCC
            [14] => 3g14
            [15] => 3g15
            [20] => DDDDD
            [34] => EEEEE
        )
    [3g14] => Array
        (
            [49] => FFFFF
        )
    [3g15] => Array
        (
            [50] => GGGGG
        )
)
```

I would like it to become an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [1g27] => Array
        (
            [42] => AAAAA
            [52] => BBBBB
            [2g4] => Array
            (
                [9] => CCCCC
                [3g14] => Array
                (
                    [49] => FFFFF
                )
                [3g15] => Array
                (
                    [50] => GGGGG
                )
                [20] => DDDDD
                [34] => EEEEE
        )
)
```

Notice that the values of the original array are also keys found in the original array. When there is a match between a value and an array, I want the array to replace the value (and rename that value's key).

I have tried foreach and array_walk_recursive, but I can't figure it out. (See following attempt which only goes 1 level deep.)

```
function inflate($flatree, $array)
    {
    global $inflatedtree;
    foreach ($array as $arraykey => $arrayvalue)
        {
        $inflatedtree[$arraykey] = $arrayvalue;
        if (array_key_exists($arrayvalue, $flatree))
            {
            $inflatedtree[$arrayvalue] = $flatree[$arrayvalue];
            inflate($flatree, $inflatedtree[$arrayvalue]);
            }
        }
    }
inflate($flatree, $flatree['1g27']);
```

using this function, however, gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [42] => AAAAA
    [52] => BBBBB
    [2g4] => Array
        (
            [9] => CCCCC
            [14] => 3g14
            [15] => 3g15
            [20] => DDDDD
            [34] => EEEEE
        )

    [3g14] => Array
        (
            [49] => FFFFF
        )
    [3g15] => Array
        (
            [50] => GGGGG
        )
)
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I just added it above, @iswinky

Comment: @James, my question is: how can I take an array that's 2 levels deep and turn it into one that's _n_ levels deep? I'm just wondering if this can be done and how.

Comment: It can be done, as long as it's a valid reason (i.e. often is better to make it a 3 level deep at the source - when it's created). How you do it depends on which current key & value pairs you want to be a new sub-array - i.e. your example, when you create the new sub level array, will it always be `2g4` you split from (etc)? Also, what reason do you wish to do this? I know not your question, and I could be wrong, but it looks like you're overcomplicating it. i.e. I don;t see a reason why `2g4` needs to be an array of `1g27`, rather than it's own top level array.

Comment: @James, I agree that one might as well just create the array that way to begin with. It's more of a conceptual thing and I'm trying to expand my thinking.

Comment: @adamrowe It's not too hard once you understand the structure is simply - An array has keys and values, and array values can be arrays, and this is all the way on. Make a more simple array, perhaps with a more familiar data set. Perhaps a staff array, and each staff has their own array with keys/values, and then each staff array has a sub array to store secure data, which as a separate array can be perhaps handled differently (encrypted etc), `array( joe => array( haircolour => green, age => 25, array(pin => 1234) ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the global variable $inflatedtree by a local one, which is the return value of the function inflate(). This return value is the new build branch.

```
function inflate($flatree, $array)
{
    $inflatedtree = array();
    foreach ($array as $arraykey => $arrayvalue) {
        if (array_key_exists($arrayvalue, $flatree)) {
            $inflatedtree[$arrayvalue] = inflate($flatree, $flatree[$arrayvalue]);
        } else {
            $inflatedtree[$arraykey] = $arrayvalue;
        }
    }
    return $inflatedtree;
}
```

I use a function start() for the initial call to get back the array as wished. Calling inflate() directly will return the inner array.

```
function start($flatree, $key)
{
    return array($key => inflate($flatree, $flatree[$key]));
}

$result_tree = start($flatree, '1g27');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why your code should only go one level deep. It seems that you are calling the recursive function properly. The only error is that the key is not renamed but copied to a new name. You need to delete the old value like this

```
function inflate($flatree, $array)
{
global $inflatedtree;
foreach ($array as $arraykey => $arrayvalue)
    {
    $inflatedtree[$arraykey] = $arrayvalue;
    if (array_key_exists($arrayvalue, $flatree))
        {
        unset($inflatedtree[$arraykey]);
        //now the new stuff is only at $arrayvalue, not $arraykey
        $inflatedtree[$arrayvalue] = $flatree[$arrayvalue];
        inflate($flatree, $inflatedtree[$arrayvalue]);
        }
    }
}
inflate($flatree, $flatree['1g27']);
```

**If your code ran on the example data does not give example results, then please post what array it makes otherwise.**

Comment: thanks @Kyborek. I just added an example of what the function (even with the unset) gives me in the original question