# looping array value with function php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, twig

I'm trying to create multi level dropdown menu with mysql as store data, and i use twig as theme engine, i know there is ton of code outside but, all of them HTML as the output, since i use twig, so i need array as the output, and let twig render it,(or maybe there is other option, let me know if so).
this code work if i use html as output. but if  i change to array as output the problem is 2nd menu level only show 1 array or first array, it not loop.
this is my array output from mysql query ,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Dashboard
            [link] => 1.html
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Master Data
            [link] => 2.html
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => submaster
            [link] => 11.html
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => submaster
            [link] => 12.html
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
```

and here is code i trying to convert, i mean before it code html  as the output (ul>li>ul>li>/li>/ul>/li>/lu)

```
$id = '';
function sub($items, $id){
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
            return array("link" =>$item['link'],"title"=>$item['title']);
            sub($items, $item['id']);
        }
    }
}
foreach($allmenu as $data){
    if($data['parent_id'] == 0){
        $id = $data['id'];
        $utama[]= array("link"=>$data['link'],"title"=>$data['title'],"sub"=>sub($allmenu, $id));
    }
}
```

and this is the output from above code

```
Array
(
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [link] => 1.html
                    [title] => Dashboard
                    [sub] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [link] => 2.html
                    [title] => Master Data
                    [sub] => Array
                        (
                            [link] => 11.html
                            [title] => Kampus
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

see.. in 2nd array (master data) it should two array right? with link 11.html and 12.html.
if there is mistake from my code let me know, if there is link to do this job, let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's function `sub()` breaks iteration after finding the first child element due to a return. Better build up an array with all child elements of the given parent `$id` and return this array at the end of the function:

```
function sub($items, $id){
    $subarray = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
            $subarray[] = array(
                "link"  => $item['link'],
                "title" => $item['title'],
                "sub"   => sub($items, $item['id']),
            );
        }
    }
    return $subarray;
}
```

I also integrated the call of `sub()` within build up of the sub array. A disadvantage is that for every call of function `sub()` the hole menu array is iterated. This could still be improved in a next version.

Here is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => 1.html
            [title] => Dashboard
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link] => 2.html
            [title] => Master Data
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [link] => 11.html
                            [title] => submaster
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [link] => 12.html
                            [title] => submaster
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

In addition some further improvements: To remove the empty sub-menu arrays I include a test. The default value of parameter is set to `$id = 0`. With this there is no need to pass the parent id for the initial call. Now there is no need for the foreach loop in main program any more. You can call `sub()` directly. Using the same variable names as the OP the program looks like this:

```
function sub($items, $id = 0){
    $subarray = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id) {
            $submenu = array(
                "link"  => $item['link'],
                "title" => $item['title'],
            );
            $subsubmenu = sub($items, $item['id']);
            if (!empty($subsubmenu)) {
                $submenu['sub'] = $subsubmenu;
            }
            $subarray[] = $submenu;
        }
    }
    return $subarray;
}

$utama = sub($allmenu);
```

---

Another example on how you could transfer a 2-level-depth array into a mutli-level-depth array can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26367603/4137828).

Answer (score 0):

ok i change a little from your code.

```
 function sub($items, $id){
    $subarray = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
           $submenu = sub($items, $item['id']);
            if (empty($submenu)) {
            $subarray[] = array("link" => $item['link'], "title" => $item['title']);
        } else {
            $subarray[]= array("link" => $item['link'], "title" => $item['title'], "sub" => $submenu);
        }

        }
    }
    return $subarray;
}
```

just like array in $utama, if there is a sub write it, and there is typo from your code `"sub"   => sub($allmenu, $id)`,  it should be  `"sub"   => sub($items, $item['id'),`  btw thanks alot, you save my life, with this i can create alot  nested menu.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I oversaw the misuse of `$allmenu` in `sub()`. I edited this in my answer. Putting the test for an empty sub-menu in `sub()` is also an good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work

```
function sub($items, $id){
        foreach($items as $item){
            if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
                $sub = sub($items, $item['id']);
                if(!empty($sub))
                    return array("link" =>$item['link'],"title"=>$item['title'],"sub"=>$sub);
                return array("link" =>$item['link'],"title"=>$item['title']);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($allmenu as $data){
        if($data['parent_id'] == 0){
            $id = $data['id'];
            $utama[]= array("link"=>$data['link'],"title"=>$data['title'],"sub"=>sub($allmenu, $id));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP's function `sub()` breaks iteration after finding the first child element due to a return. Here is the same issue.